Request status Code 200, but getting failed with JSON Authentican error
Earlier we used to run a job via scheduling tool, client had give a website i.,e via Postman it was working and via scheduling tool(redwood). Used to extract the XML data and load to the table via ETL...
Now they changed the website(URL), when we try to debug via scheduling tool(redwood), we are getting request status code is 200, but API response is "JSON Authentication Invalid User and Password"  (The same credentials when we run from Postman it is working)
Any feedback or suggestion are welcome..
Thanks,
